# How do I remove everything after first whitespace or certain number of characters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a date string that I need to simplify in Ruby:

```
2008-10-09 20:30:40
```

I only want the day portion:

```
2008-10-09
```

I'm looking for a gsub line that will strip everything after a set number of characters or the first whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer to use as simple a solution as I can. Using `gsub` is needlessly complex. Either of these will do it:

```
str = '2008-10-09 20:30:40'
str[/(\S+)/, 1] #=> "2008-10-09"
str[0, 10] #=> "2008-10-09"
```

Answer (score 2):

Literal solution:

```
date.gsub(/(.{10}).*/, '\1')

date.gsub(/\s.*/, '')

date[0, 10]
```

Better solution: Treat it as a DateTime object - then you can format it as you wish:

```
date = DateTime.now
date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") # America
date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") # Europe
```

Comment: Those appear to return the time? Not the date?

Answer (score 1):

If the format is consistantly like that,

```
'2008-10-09 20:30:40'[/[-\d]+/] # => "2008-10-19"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'2008-10-09 20:30:40'.split[0]
```